# Passive Voice of Future Continuous tense

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I am learning English Grammar from a very popular book in Indian market (you can get it from [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=plinth%20to%20paramount%20pdf)) and it very distinctively mentions that Passive Voice of Future Continuous tense is not possible.

However, when I searched online there are posts/blogs (for example [this](https://www.learnesl.net/active-and-passive-voice-of-future-continuous-tense/) and [this](https://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/activepassive.html)) which mentions rules for Passive Voice of Future Continuous tense.

Could someone please clarify, I am confused as both are very reliable sources?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide example sentences?

Comment: You should add the examples to your question, not just link to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but don't do it.

> I will be playing tennis.  (active)
>
> Tennis will be being played. (passive)

I can think of no situations where one would need use this verb form. It is such a mouthful that you should avoid it.

Comment: The active vs passive examples by James are correct. I would not say "don't do it." I would say that if you think carefully about why you make your choices of verb tenses, you might go your entire life without ever finding a legitimate reason to make this particular tense choice. But logically, it is quite valid.

Comment: An example of this might be, “It’s going to be a wild party! Drinks will be had and memories will be made!”

Comment: @JoshBeck "Drinks will be being drunk; memories will be being made" is a legitimate, but artificial. example. But I concur with Ross, it's valid but unused.